# Projection XY with maplibre

Tags: leaflet, mapbox-gl-js, maplibre-gl

I am using Leaflet with **crs: L.CRS.Simple** for a game map(XY coords) with "leaflet-rastercoords" https://github.com/commenthol/leaflet-rastercoords
and want to switch to maplibre (aka Mapbox). But they use different unproject methods (results):

**Leaflet**
`map.unproject([900,900])` 
(and here I can use a zoom level like `map.unproject([900,900], 5)`)
`D {lat: -3.515625, lng: 3.515625}`

**Maplibre**
`map.unproject([900,900])`
`Ku {lng: -175.4993011138676, lat: 84.56509264504697}`

Is there a way to use the same unproject method in maplibre as in Leaflet to produce the same results?

This plugin is using Leafelt `this.map.unproject(coords, this.zoom);`
[here](https://github.com/commenthol/leaflet-rastercoords/blob/564731dc593e24a2f1f173fc736e46fe8f16a5b1/rastercoords.js#L60-L62)

Comment: Since Mapbox supports only Web Mercator projection (EPSG:3857), you are out of luck here regarding the same or even similar behavior regarding coordinates as in Leaflet with `LCRS.Simple` projection.

Comment: MapBox GL does support a few other projections now https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/pull/11124 but the MapLibre fork doesn't https://github.com/maplibre/maplibre-gl-js/issues/168.

Comment: Please edit your title, it is either MapLibre of MapBox GL. MapLibre is a fork that was born when MapBox changed the license of MapBox GL.

Comment: @user30184 but it looks like there is no CRS.Simple

Comment: @user30184 Thanks for clarification!